# JPA AttributeOverride.column() should override all columns

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ejb

I try overwrite columns mapping on @MappedSuperclass, when I try to deploy, I get the next exception:

**Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: AttributeOverride.column() should override all columns for now**

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need overwrite all columns into @MappedSuperclass. Best.